# Fixed-Point Free Involutions

Tags: permutations, generating-functions, permutation-cycles, fixed-points, involutions

I am looking to solve this problem:

A permutation $\alpha$ on the set $\{1, 2, . . . , n\}$ is an involution if $\alpha^2 (i)=i$ for all $i = 1,2,\ldots,n$. An element is a fixed point of $\alpha$ if $α(i)=i$. Use exponential generating function to find the number of fixed-point-free involutions on the set $\{1,2,\ldots,2m\}$.

---

Firstly, I am a bit confused as to the definition of an involution. I see online that an involution is a permutation that is it's own inverse, but I am not quite clear on what that means exactly. I saw somewhere that, for example, "the four involution permutations on $3$ elements are $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{1,3,2\}$, $\{2,1,3\}$, and $\{3,2,1\}$." Is there a reason that $\{2,3,1\}$ and $\{3,1,2\}$ are excluded from this list?

Any guidance on the definition of an involution as well as how to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens with an involution when you factor it in cycles?

Comment: The inverse of {2,3,1} is {3,1,2} . Or, if you compose  {2,3,1} with itself, it is not equal to {1,2,3} . Therefore it is not an involution.

Comment: The EGF of $\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}} \textsc{SET}(\textsc{CYC}_{=2}(\mathcal{Z}))$ is $\exp(z^2/2)$ by inspection, which points us to [OEIS A123023](https://oeis.org/A123023).

Comment: So does $\alpha^2$ refer to the composition of a permutation with itself?

Comment: The permutation $\alpha^2$ is what you obtain when the image of $q$ is what you get after two steps along the directed cycle where $q$ resides i.e. $\alpha(\alpha(q)).$

Comment: The notation $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$ is very bad for permutations, since it's used for sets, where the order of the elements is irrelevant. To say $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{1,3,2\}$ are the same as sets but different as permutations can only cause confusion.

Comment: If the answer posted by Halla solves your problem, Natalie, you have the option of "accepting" it by clicking in the check mark next to it. If it doesn't answer your question, you can leave a comment on it to let Halla (and the rest of us) know what still needs answering.

Comment: Are you still here, Natalie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An **involution** is a permutation that is its own inverse, but that can be a bit hard to parse at first. Let's see a concrete example:

The map $x \mapsto -x$ from $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is an involution. Intuitively why? Because we flip $\mathbb{Z}$ across $0$. Formally why? Because if we apply this transformation twice, we have $-(-x) = x$, and we've gotten back where we started. This is the defining characteristic of an involution: we can flip once, but if we flip again we get back where we started.

(As a quick exercise: consider the $8$ symmetries of a square. Which ones are involutions? The answer is below the fold.)

> We want the symmetries of a square that, if we do them twice, we get back where we started. There are $4$ obvious "flips" -- flip vertically, flip horizontally, and flip across either of the two diagonals. There's also the bonus involution "rotate $180^\circ$". The identity is an involution for kind of silly reasons, so we're up to $6$ involutions. The remaining two symmetries are a $90^\circ$ rotation clockwise or counterclockwise, and neither of these are involutions since if you do them twice you don't get back where you started.

Every involution pairs up an element with somebody else, just look to see who you get flipped to. So the $x \mapsto -x$ involution from earlier pairs $1$ with $-1$, $2$ with $-2$, etc... Except there's a special point: $0$ gets paired with itself! We say that $0$ is a **fixed point** of the involution, and these are very special. Fixed points hold the answer to lots of counting problems, but I digress.

In this problem, we want to count the number of involutions where everybody gets a friend. That is, we want our involution to have no fixed points.

(As another quick exercise, can you come up with a fixed point-free involution on $\mathbb{Z}$? Again, I'll include one under the fold)

> There are lots of options, but $x \mapsto \begin{cases} x+1 & x \text{ is even} \\ x-1 & x \text{ is odd} \end{cases}$ works. Notice $0$ gets paired with $1$, $2$ gets paired with $3$, etc. Can you formally show that this really is an involution?

Now, it should be clear that a fixed point free involution (on a finite set) can only exist if we're permuting an even number of things. After all, if everyone has a friend, then we have $2m$ many elements where $m$ is the number of pairs. For your example of involutions on a $3$ element set, notice we can:

- swap $1$ and $2$ (leaving $3$ fixed)
- swap $1$ and $3$ (leaving $2$ fixed)
- swap $2$ and $3$ (leaving $1$ fixed)
- don't swap anyone (leaving $1$, $2$, and $3$ fixed)

At this point, can you answer your own question about why the remaining two permutations are *not* involutions?

---

Ok, on to the main point of your question. How can we *count* the number of fixed point free involutions on the set $[2m] = \{1,2,3,\ldots,2m-1, 2m\}$? It's hard to know precisely how to answer this without knowing what aspects of exponential generating functions you've seen. But here's one approach which is hinting at the idea of [species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_species). I'm going to be somewhat quick with my description (this answer is already quite long), but you can read more in [these](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Emhaiman/math172-spring10/exponential.pdf) excellent notes.

We know that an involution without fixed points divides a set into pairs. Conversely, if we divide a set into pairs, then we get a unique involution by swapping the two paired elements.

So we want to partition $2m$ into blocks of size $2$. In terms of "structure" (again, see the linked notes), this means we want to

- divide $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 2m-1, 2m\}$ into blocks
- each block should have structure "I have $2$ elements"
- the set of blocks should have no structure

But this nested notion of putting structure on blocks, each of which has structure is *exactly* where exponential generating functions show their full power! This maneuver corresponds to the *composition* of generating functions!

In particular, "I have $2$ elements" is expressed by the exponential generating function $\frac{x^2}{2!}$ (do you see why?). Then "I have no structure" is expressed by $e^x$ (again, do you see why?)

So now, by the composition theorem for exponential generating functions, we see the number of ways to divide $m$ objects into blocks of size $2$ is the composite of the above functions. That is, $e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$. Indeed, we can check that

$$e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} = 1 + \frac{x^2}{2!} + 3 \frac{x^4}{4!} + 15 \frac{x^6}{6!} + 105 \frac{x^8}{8!} + \ldots$$

which matches what we expect for small values of $m$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Sorry, two questions. 1) How do we know that involutions divides a set into pairs? I'm still  learning about involutions, but from the example I had given, it seemed that they were put into three's.  2) "In particular, "I have 2 elements" is expressed by the exponential generating function $\frac{x^2}{2!}$ (do you see why?). Then "I have no structure" is expressed by $e^x$ (again, do you see why?)" I'm having a bit of trouble following this. Could you explain a bit further? Thanks!

Comment: @Natalie -- Of course! For (1), this is what the first half of my answer was about. Maybe a more symbolic treatment will resonate with you better? If $\sigma$ is a permutation of some finite set, then it's an involution if and only if $\sigma^2(x) = x$ for each $x$. But what does this mean? Well, either $\sigma(x) = x$, or $\sigma(x) \neq x$. In the first case, we say $x$ is a **fixed point** of $\sigma$. In the second, $x$ gets a friend (call it $y$) so $\sigma(x) = y$ and $\sigma(y) = \sigma^2(x) = x$. So the involution pairs up $x$ and $y$. If there are no fixed points, each $x$ gets a $y$.

Comment: For (2), I would mainly recommend reading the [article I linked](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Emhaiman/math172-spring10/exponential.pdf), as it's a bit too tricky a concept to explain in an mse answer of reasonable length! The idea is that to divide a set $X$ into pairs (that is, to count involutions), we want to divide $X$ into blocks. Each block should have size $2$, and we have no requirements on the structure of the blocks themselves. There's a famous theorem about exponential generating functions that says (continued)

Comment: (continued) Let $A$ be an exponential generating function (egf) so that $\frac{a_n}{n!}$ is the number of ways to build an $A$ with $n$ elements. Let $B$ be an egf so that $\frac{b_n}{n!}$ is the number of ways to build a $B$ with $n$ elements. Then a natural question is "what does the egf $A(B(x))$ count?" Well, it turns out that if you have a set of size $n$, which you divide into blocks so that each block has the structure counted by $B$ and the collection of blocks has the structure counted by $A$, then the $x^n$ coefficient of $A(B(x))$ tells you how many ways you can do this. (continued)

Comment: (continued) So for us, we want to divide a set into blocks, each of size $2$. The egf for "I have $2$ elements" is $0\frac{x^0}{0!} + 0\frac{x^1}{1!} + 1 \frac{x^2}{2!} + 0 \frac{x^3}{3!} + \ldots$ (again, do you see why?). Then the egf for "I have no structure" is saying that any set of size $n$ will do, but there's exactly one way to have a set of size $n$ with no structure. So the egf is $1 \frac{x^0}{0!} + 1 \frac{x^1}{1!} + 1 \frac{x^2}{2!} + 1 \frac{x^3}{3!}  + \ldots$. This is recognizable as $e^x$. (continued)

Comment: (continued) So, putting these pieces together, we find $e^x$ composed with $\frac{x^2}{2}$ should be the correct generating function, and that's exactly what we found in the main answer: $e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$.